# Java Heap space with jpa native Query

Tags: java, jpa, heap-memory, nativequery

I am having an OOME problem when trying to run a native SQL query through the jpa / hibernate EM.
The treatment serves to make millions of insertion per pack of 50.

Here is code of my algorithm:

```
private void createNewJetonsForIndividus(boolean isGlobal, List<String> entreprises, List<String> services,
                                         String user, Timestamp dateDB) {

    LocalDateTime timer = LocalDateTime.now();

    List<Object[]> MinMaxId = getMinMaxIdDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation(
            isGlobal, entreprises, services);

    if (null != MinMaxId.get(0)[0]) {

        int idStart =  ((BigInteger) MinMaxId.get(0)[0]).intValue();
        int idEnd = idStart + PAS;
        int idMax = ((BigInteger) MinMaxId.get(0)[1]).intValue();
        int nbRowsTotal = 0;
        Logger.debug("Droits Individus : ID Min {}  -  ID Max {}", idStart, idMax);


        do {
            int finalIdStart = idStart;
            int finalIdEnd = idEnd;
            callTransaction(() -> create(false, true,isGlobal, entreprises, services, finalIdStart,
                    finalIdEnd, user, dateDB));
            idStart = idEnd + 1;
            idEnd = idEnd + PAS;
        }
        while (idMax > idEnd);

    }
}
```

the method is used to calculate the id min and max of the records that interest my treatment. Subsequently, I use the create method whose code is below :

```
int nbRowsFind;

    List<Object[]> listeDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation = getDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation(
            isGlobal, entreprises, services, idStart, idEnd);

    if (ValidationUtils.isNotEmpty(listeDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation)) {

        nbRowsFind = listeDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation.size();

        StringBuilder sbJeton = new StringBuilder();
        sbJeton.append("INSERT INTO sigs_nv_jeton VALUES ");


        StringBuilder sbDroitHasJeton = new StringBuilder();

        if (isCreateForIndiv) {
            sbDroitHasJeton.append("INSERT INTO sigs_droits_individu_has_nv_jeton VALUES ");
        }

        listeDroitsIndividusActifsForCreation.stream().forEach(object -> {
            sbJeton.append("(");
            sbDroitHasJeton.append("(");

            BigInteger idDroit = (BigInteger) object[0];

            String jetonGenerated = IdJetonGenerator.codeGenerator(idDroit.toString(), DateUtils.now());
            sbJeton.append("'").append(jetonGenerated).append("', ");

            appendDate(sbJeton, object[1]);
            appendDate(sbJeton, object[2]);
            sbJeton.append(0).append(", ");
            sbJeton.append(0).append(", ");
            sbJeton.append("'").append(dateDB).append("', ");
            sbJeton.append("'").append(user).append("'");

            sbDroitHasJeton.append(idDroit).append(",'").append(jetonGenerated).append("'");

            sbJeton.append("),");
            sbDroitHasJeton.append("),");
        });


        String requestJeton = sbJeton.toString();
        sbJeton.delete(33, sbJeton.length());
        requestJeton = requestJeton.substring(0, requestJeton.length() - 1);
        jpaApi.em().createNativeQuery(requestJeton).executeUpdate();

        String requestDroitHasJeton = sbDroitHasJeton.toString();
        sbDroitHasJeton.delete(54, sbDroitHasJeton.length());
        requestDroitHasJeton = requestDroitHasJeton.substring(0, requestDroitHasJeton.length() - 1);
        **jpaApi.em().createNativeQuery(requestDroitHasJeton).executeUpdate();**


        **jpaApi.em().flush();
        jpaApi.em().clear();**
    }
```

When I analyze the Heap Dump, I notice that despite the flush and clear, queries are still referenced in the SessionFactory, is this normal?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nc6ek.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flush is executing changes made in the unit of work and clear removes entities from the persistence context.

Both have nothing to do with native SQL queries. I assume that the native queries are cached anywhere else (Hibernate, JDBC...)

I would suggest that you use a prepared statement instead of your dynamic insert statement.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What I can not understand is that in the heap dump of the insertion query shows that queries are well referenced in the SessionFactory ==> Hibernation Level 1 Cache ? despite the fact that each transaction uses an instance EM that is near the end of each call. You advise me to use JDBC via the prepared statement ?

Comment: No my advice is to use a insert statement with place holders (?). like this Hibernate will create a prepared statement and the statement exists only once.

Comment: thank you for your explanations. I take this opportunity to put my new implementation using the Scrollable ResultSet & preparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

This is my new implementation :

```
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    int nbRows = 0;

    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        try {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryGetDroitsEntreprisesActifsForCreation(isGlobal, entreprises, services));
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                nbRows += 1;
                queryInsertJetonsAndLinkDroitsJeton(isCreateForEntreprise, isCreateForIndiv, connection, resultSet,
                        user, dateDB);
            }
            System.out.println(nbRows);
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
    }
```

The method "queryGetDroitsEntreprisesActifsForCreation" returns a SQL query in String.
The method "queryInsertJetonsAndLinkDroitsJeton" use the famous PreparedStatement :

```
PreparedStatement psJeton = null;
    PreparedStatement psDroitJeton = null;
    try {
        String sbJeton = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ";

        psJeton = connection.prepareStatement(sbJeton);

        String jetonGenerated;
        if (isCreateForEntreprise) {
            jetonGenerated = IdJetonGenerator.codeGenerator(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id_e")), DateUtils.now());
        } else {
            jetonGenerated = IdJetonGenerator.codeGenerator(String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id_i")), DateUtils.now());
        }
        psJeton.setString(1, jetonGenerated);
        psJeton.setString(2, ContextType.GD.name());
        psJeton.setString(3, JetonType.ANONYME.name());
        psJeton.setInt(4, 1);
        psJeton.setTimestamp(5, resultSet.getTimestamp("dt_debut"));
        psJeton.setTimestamp(6, resultSet.getTimestamp("dt_fin"));
        psJeton.setInt(7, 0);
        psJeton.setInt(8, 0);
        psJeton.setInt(9, 0);
        psJeton.setInt(10, 0);
        psJeton.setTimestamp(11, dateDB);
        psJeton.setString(12, user);
        psJeton.setTimestamp(13, dateDB);
        psJeton.setString(14, user);
        psJeton.executeUpdate();


        String sbDroitHasJeton = null;
        if (isCreateForEntreprise) {
            sbDroitHasJeton = "INSERT INTO sigs_dej VALUES (?, ?)";
        }
        if (isCreateForIndiv) {
            sbDroitHasJeton = "INSERT INTO sigs_dij VALUES (?, ?)";
        }

        psDroitJeton = connection.prepareStatement(sbDroitHasJeton);
        if(isCreateForEntreprise) {
            psDroitJeton.setInt(1, resultSet.getInt("id_e"));
        } else {
            psDroitJeton.setInt(1, resultSet.getInt("id_i"));
        }

        psDroitJeton.setString(2, jetonGenerated);
        psDroitJeton.executeUpdate();


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (psJeton != null) {
            psJeton.close();
        }
        if (psDroitJeton != null) {
            psDroitJeton.close();
        }

    }
```

I hope this is the best implementation of PreparedStatement & Scrollable ResultSet